# Tidying (v untidy) data in R / Shiny – difficulty dealing with lists

Tags: r, shiny

relatively new to Shiny and trying to work through some issues with an app I'm making that uses .gpx files.  Currently, at some point the lists aren't able to bind together. A big part of struggling to debug it is I can't get shiny to return any data, even immediately after import. This isn't helped by the fact that the files are a very messy concoction of lists within lists etc. To make things more difficult I haven't been able to make a reproducible data sample, as dput(head(df))) returns all of the lists, so the start looks something like:

```
list(list(metadata = NULL, bounds = NULL, waypoints = NULL, tracks = list( list(Evening Ride= structure(list(lon = c(-0.12927)
```

with thousand more rows
I've gone through the dput() output and tried to put together a working sample but haven't been able to get it working as the data does. If anyone has a function to get `dput()` to work with this sort of list data please let me know. However, `str(df[[1]])`, returns

```
List of 5
 $ metadata : NULL
 $ bounds   : NULL
 $ waypoints: NULL
 $ tracks   :List of 1
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ Evening Ride:'data.frame': 1746 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. .. ..$ lon : num [1:1746] -0.129 -0.129 -0.129 -0.129 -0.129 ...
  .. .. ..$ lat : num [1:1746] 51.5 51.5 51.5 51.5 51.5 ...
  .. .. ..$ ele : chr [1:1746] "25.3" "25.3" "25.2" "25.2" ...
  .. .. ..$ time: chr [1:1746] "2019-10-21T17:09:29Z" "2019-10-21T17:09:30Z" "2019-10-21T17:09:33Z" "2019-10-21T17:09:35Z" ...
 $ routes   : NULL
```

Anyone, hopefully someone can spot where my code is going wrong  :)

So, if I want to import one file my code looks like this (and this works):

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotKML)
# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose gpx Files",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c(".gpx")),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Data file ----
      plotOutput("contents")

    )

  )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$contents <- renderPlot({

    req(input$file1)

    tryCatch(
      {
        df <-
          plotKML::readGPX(input$file1$datapath)        

        list_row_frame <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, df)) %>% 
          as_data_frame()


        unnested_ride <- list_row_frame %>%
          mutate(ride = seq.int(nrow(list_row_frame))) %>% 
          unnest() %>% 
          unnest()


      }
    )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This works without error. However, when I want to change the code to input multiple .gpx files I run into the error `'incompatible lengths: x, y'`

I will just server function as UI is the same.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    req(input$file1)

    tryCatch(
      {
        df <- 
          rbindlist(lapply(input$file1$datapath, plotKML::readGPX), 
                    use.names = TRUE, fill = T)

        list_row_frame <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, df)) %>% 
          as_data_frame()


        unnested_ride <- list_row_frame %>%
          unnest() %>% 
          unnest() 

        return(unnested_ride[[1]])

      }
    )
  })

}
```

This code really is bad at times, but due to never being able to get return(var) / return(var[[1]]) to return anything I'm almost doing it blind. I have tried to change unnest() to unlist() but then I get an error about character variables. If anyone has any suggestions I'd be so grateful. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Modify your code so that your function processes each file individually.  Then `lapply` that function to a list of input files.  Then `bind_rows` the list of data frames returned from `lapply` into a single data frame.  That's compact, efficient and lets you identify which file(s) is/are problematic.

Comment: @Limey Thanks for your answer. why doesn't the current call to `lapply` `readGPX` process each file individually? Also, are you sure that `lapply` is returning a df, it seems to me like its a list, with a df for $evening_ride? If it makes a difference I don't think any files are problematic, when running a (slightly different) script not in Shiny there are no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Making my earlier answer more concrete.  I managed to find a GPX file to work with [here](https://www.clivecatton.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/downloads/coasttocoast.gpx).  I'll use tibbles rather than data frames simply because they print in a nicer fashion.  Reversion to data.frames should have no effect whatsoever.

## Read in the data file and poke around to see what we  have:

```
library(plotKML)
library(tidyverse)

df <- readGPX("coasttocoast.gpx")
names(df)
[1] "metadata"  "bounds"    "waypoints" "tracks"    "routes"  
length(df$bounds)
[1] 0
length(df$tracks)
[1] 0
length(df$waypoints)
[1] 5
length(df$routes)
[1] 13
df$waypoints
         lon      lat       name  sym          type
1 -0.5312896 54.43030 C2C FINISH Flag LDP:c2c route
2 -3.6100834 54.48718  C2C START Flag LDP:c2c route
head(df$routes[[1]])
        lon      lat   name  cmt desc sym      type
1 -3.608879 54.48796 WP0101 <NA> <NA> Dot Waypoints
2 -3.607836 54.49090 WP0102 <NA> <NA> Dot Waypoints
3 -3.607223 54.49099 WP0103 <NA> <NA> Dot Waypoints
4 -3.609015 54.49142 WP0104 <NA> <NA> Dot Waypoints
5 -3.609934 54.49123 WP0105 <NA> <NA> Dot Waypoints
6 -3.610693 54.49090 WP0106 <NA> <NA> Dot Waypoints
```

So I can only test my approach on waypoints and routes

## Write the convertToCommonFormat function

It's not as complicated as it looks.  It's only six statements long.  I've just formatted it so you don't have to scroll.

```
convertToCommonFormat <- function(df=NA, x=NA, source, file, idx=NA) {
  if (is.na(x)) x <- df[[source]]
  if (is.null(x)) return(
                    tibble(
                      FileName=character(), 
                      Source=character(), 
                      Index=NA_integer_
                    )
                  )
  if (is.data.frame(x)) {
    # Using tibble rather than dataframe simply for ease of printing
    return(
      as_tibble(
        x %>% add_column(
                FileName=file, 
                Source=source, 
                Index=idx, 
                .before=1
              )
      )
    )
  } else if (is.list(x)) {
    return(
      bind_rows(
        lapply(
          1:length(x), 
          function(y) convertToCommonFormat(x=x[[y]], idx=y, file=file, source=source)
        )
      )
    )
  } else {
    print(x)
    stop(paste0("Don't know what to do with ", str(x)))
  }
}
```

Test it:

```
convertToCommonFormat(df, source="tracks", file="coasttocoast.gpx")
# A tibble: 0 x 3
# … with 3 variables: FileName <chr>, Source <chr>, Index <int>
convertToCommonFormat(df, source="waypoints", file="coasttocoast.gpx")
# A tibble: 2 x 8
  FileName         Source    Index    lon   lat name       sym   type         
  <chr>            <chr>     <lgl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <chr> <chr>        
1 coasttocoast.gpx waypoints NA    -0.531  54.4 C2C FINISH Flag  LDP:c2c route
2 coasttocoast.gpx waypoints NA    -3.61   54.5 C2C START  Flag  LDP:c2c route
convertToCommonFormat(df, source="routes", file="coasttocoast.gpx")
# A tibble: 2,371 x 10
   FileName         Source Index   lon   lat name   cmt   desc  sym   type     
   <chr>            <chr>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    
 1 coasttocoast.gpx routes     1 -3.61  54.5 WP0101 NA    NA    Dot   Waypoints
 2 coasttocoast.gpx routes     1 -3.61  54.5 WP0102 NA    NA    Dot   Waypoints
 3 coasttocoast.gpx routes     1 -3.61  54.5 WP0103 NA    NA    Dot   Waypoints
 4 coasttocoast.gpx routes     1 -3.61  54.5 WP0104 NA    NA    Dot   Waypoints
 5 coasttocoast.gpx routes     1 -3.61  54.5 WP0105 NA    NA    Dot   Waypoints
 6 coasttocoast.gpx routes     1 -3.61  54.5 WP0106 NA    NA    Dot   Waypoints
 7 coasttocoast.gpx routes     1 -3.61  54.5 WP0107 NA    NA    Dot   Waypoints
 8 coasttocoast.gpx routes     1 -3.61  54.5 WP0108 NA    NA    Dot   Waypoints
 9 coasttocoast.gpx routes     1 -3.62  54.5 WP0109 NA    NA    Dot   Waypoints
10 coasttocoast.gpx routes     1 -3.62  54.5 WP0110 NA    NA    Dot   Waypoints
# … with 2,361 more rows
```

Annoyingly, the `routes` element contains records of type `Waypoints` and the `waypoints` element contains records of type `route`.  Go figure.

Check we've got all 13 routes in there:

```
# Prove that we've got all 13 routes in there
convertToCommonFormat(df, source="routes", file="coasttocoast.gpx") %>% 
  group_by(Index) %>% summarise(N=n(), .groups="drop")
# A tibble: 13 x 2
   Index     N
   <int> <int>
 1     1   194
 2     2    16
 3     3   186
 4     4   198
 5     5   162
 6     6   215
 7     7   137
 8     8   209
 9     9   157
10    10   272
11    11   133
12    12   247
13    13   245
```

## Write the processOneFile function

```
processOneFile <- function(gpxFile) {
  df <- readGPX(gpxFile)
  tracks <- convertToCommonFormat(df, source="tracks", file=gpxFile)
  waypoints <- convertToCommonFormat(df, source="waypoints", file=gpxFile)
  routes <- convertToCommonFormat(df, source="routes", file=gpxFile)
  return(bind_rows(tracks, waypoints, routes))
}
```

And use it

```
processOneFile("coasttocoast.gpx")
# A tibble: 2,373 x 10
   FileName         Source    Index    lon   lat name       sym   type          cmt   desc 
   <chr>            <chr>     <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <chr> <chr>         <chr> <chr>
 1 coasttocoast.gpx waypoints    NA -0.531  54.4 C2C FINISH Flag  LDP:c2c route NA    NA   
 2 coasttocoast.gpx waypoints    NA -3.61   54.5 C2C START  Flag  LDP:c2c route NA    NA   
 3 coasttocoast.gpx routes        1 -3.61   54.5 WP0101     Dot   Waypoints     NA    NA   
 4 coasttocoast.gpx routes        1 -3.61   54.5 WP0102     Dot   Waypoints     NA    NA   
 5 coasttocoast.gpx routes        1 -3.61   54.5 WP0103     Dot   Waypoints     NA    NA   
 6 coasttocoast.gpx routes        1 -3.61   54.5 WP0104     Dot   Waypoints     NA    NA   
 7 coasttocoast.gpx routes        1 -3.61   54.5 WP0105     Dot   Waypoints     NA    NA   
 8 coasttocoast.gpx routes        1 -3.61   54.5 WP0106     Dot   Waypoints     NA    NA   
 9 coasttocoast.gpx routes        1 -3.61   54.5 WP0107     Dot   Waypoints     NA    NA   
10 coasttocoast.gpx routes        1 -3.61   54.5 WP0108     Dot   Waypoints     NA    NA   
# … with 2,363 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving from comment to answer because I expect to hit the character limit in the comment.  Though I accept this isn't a full answer in the normal sense of the word...

The `lapply` in your existing code *does* process each file individually.  I don't dispute that.  Apologies if I wasn't clear.

But you immediately bind the list of (lists of?) dataframes it returns before then processing the combined data frames some more.  What I wanted to suggest was writing a function which both read in the GPX file and did the necessary processing on the raw data to get that individual raw data file into a format that could then be bound together.

I'm not familiar with the `ploKML` package, but the documentation suggests that the output from `readGPX` is a list of dataframes, one for each of metadata, waypoints, tracks and routes.  [From the online doc:  `readGPX` "Reads various elements from a *.gpx file — metadata, waypoints, tracks and routes—and converts them *to dataframes*."]  (My emphasis: note the plural on dataframes.)

So, leaving metadata aside, it seems reasonable to suppose that waypoints, tracks and routes could be stored in data.frames with a common format: perhaps with columns for `Type` (waypoint/track/route), `Index` (to allow for more than one element of each type), `DateTime`, `Longitude`, `Latitude` and `Extras` (for type specific information: this could be a list column or a df column, for example).

Then my processing function would have a call to `readGPX` as its first line, then a series of steps to process the waypoints, tracks and routes, and finally a line to bind the elements into a single df representing that file.

Something like

```
processOneFile <- function(gpxFile) {
  contents <- readGPX(gpxFile)
  waypointDF <- convertToCommonFormat(contents[["waypoints"]], type="waypoint")
  trackDF <- convertToCommonFormat(contents[["tracks"]], type="track")
  routeDF <- convertToCommonFormat(contents[["routes"]], type="route")
  return(bind_rows(waypointDF, trackDF, routeDF)) 
}
```

Obviously, you'd have to write `convertToCommonFormat` as well, and you could `lapply`  the calls to it within `processOneFile` if you wanted.  Debugging calls to `print` within both `convertToCommonFormat` and `processOneFile` would help identify where problems are occurring.

Then, in your main program, you use `lapply` to process your list of files:

```
allDataInOne <- bind_rows(lapply(myListOfFiles, processOneFile))
```

Both my workflow and yours should, in theory, end up with the same result when given well-behaved input data.  I think the advantage of mine is that, when the input data files *aren't* well behaved, it's easier to work out where the problems are.

Sorry I can't give you a concrete example, but as you can't provide source data (for obvious reasons) and the example file in the `plotKML` manual isn't available, I don't know of an easy source of test data.

Comment: perhaps it’s worth mentioning that another benefit to your method is that you could write [unit tests](https://testthat.r-lib.org/) for each of your functions to aid in isolating and debugging the issues and making the Shiny app more stable.